# Media queries on mobile do not work even after the viewport meta tag

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I realize this is a duplicate, but the solutions I have tried do not work. For some reason, after adding the viewport meta tag, my media queries do not work on mobile. Does anyone know why?

Edit: The reason why was because my screen wasn't zoomed in at 100% width.

Here is the code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1260px) {
    .container {
        margin-top: 300px;
    }

    h2 {
        font-size: 3vw;
        width: 800px;
    }

    p {
        font-size: 2.5vw;
        width: 800px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 550px) {
    h2 {
        width: 330px;
        font-size: 5vw
    }

    p {
        font-size: 4vw;
        width: 330px;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. Your code worked for me. `h2` and `p` changed below breakpoint of 550px and from 550px to 1260px.

I'm using meta `<meta name="viewport"
  content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />`

but media queries worked even without it.

Maybe the issue is with your actual markup.  Can you share that?

Comment: Hey thanks for replying! I noticed that media queries differ from Live Server compared to the actual website. It's strange. Do you know why?

Comment: Are you referring to Live Server in VS Code?

Comment: Indeed. I am hosting the website right now and using my iPad to check for responsiveness. It still looks different but I think it's because I am using pixels instead of em. I heard it's better to use em so I will try using that.

Comment: I'm old, and started in print, so I still use pixels across the board, that said, I probably need more media queries to satisfy all conditions.  Yes, `em` is much better according to most experts, especially with regard to supporting accessibility, I just have yet to make the switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this a few months ago and now I realized it was because my screen was zoomed in. If you have this problem, make sure your window is set to 100% zoom.